# How to change Bootstrap width that triggers responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a code like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 px-1 bg-dark">
            <div class="py-2 sticky-top flex-grow-1">
                <div class="nav flex-sm-column">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link d-none d-sm-inline">Sidebar</a>
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <h1>Main Area</h1>
            <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics,
                raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation.
                Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>

            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
                readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
                forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>

            <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics,
                raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation.
                Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>

            <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics,
                raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation.
                Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6GLE5UA2TUM (You can press run to run code above)

This code moves left sidebar to top of the screen when the width of resolution goes less than about 580px. However, I want to change this behavior that it moves left side bar to top of the screen when the width of resolution goess less than 1024px, not 580px.

How can I do this with Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `col-sm-*` and `flex-sm-column` classes to `col-lg-*` and `flex-lg-column`... If you check Bootstrap documentation, the `lg` classes target the `1024px` mark

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 px-1 bg-dark">
        <div class="py-2 sticky-top flex-grow-1">
          <div class="nav flex-lg-column">
            <a href="" class="nav-link d-none d-sm-inline">Sidebar</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="main">
        <h1>Main Area</h1>
        <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics,
          raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby
          chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>

        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade
          disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache
          food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>

        <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics,
          raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby
          chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>

        <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics,
          raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby
          chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```